# Deleting mongodb subdocument on certain date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, collections, agenda

I have a collection which stores document that can have multiple subdocument (e.g. a group collection with multiple votings). My goal is to delete certain subdocuments on a certain date. I thought about using a package like "agenda" to cron-like delete certain subdocuments. Are there any more efficient or easier ways to do that

Comment: Post some code here

Comment: Share yr schema so will help you in this case